# Print lines from config files for specific section only

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, pcre

I have config files with many sections. I need to collect all lines from specific section. The section may appear several times in the one file. 
For example:

```
serviceA:
   ports:
     8080
     1323
serviceB:
  test:
      MMMM
  ports:
     8081
     3123
  network:
    ddddd
```

I read this article https://www.shellhacks.com/sed-awk-print-lines-between-two-patterns/ and start.

Pattern for the start of section is simple, it is `/ports:/` but pattern for the end of section is not so simple it could be any name, something like `[a-zA-Z]+:`

I try to use pattern `[a-zA-Z]+:` in awk and sed.

In awk. It print only names of sections

```
awk '/ports:/,/[a-zA-Z]+:/' file
    ports:
    ports:
```

In sed. It print from first ports to end of file

```
sed -n '/ports:/,/[a-zA-Z]+:/p' file
ports:
         8080
         1323
    serviceB:
      test:
         MMMM
      ports:
         8081
         3123
      network:
        ddddd
```

I thought the problem was that pattern `[a-zA-Z]+:` match with ports: and deсide to exclude ports:.
 `^\s*((?!ports)[a-zA-Z]+:)+` 
This pattern works ok in online regex tester - https://regex101.com/

awk prints from first ports to end of file

```
awk '/ports:/,/^\s*((?!ports)[a-zA-Z]+:)+/' file
ports:
             8080
             1323
        serviceB:
          test:
             MMMM
          ports:
             8081
             3123
          network:
            ddddd
```

Currently, I found only one case

```
awk '/ports:/,/network:|serviceB:/' 
  ports:
      8080
      1323
serviceB:
  ports:
      8081
      3123
network:
```

But, I do not know all possible names for sections.
I need an universal solution.

Comment: Thanks to @potong and karakfa. Both versions are good. As I see the solution is you must first set regex for the end of the section and then the regex for its beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your data format, something like this should work

```
$ awk '/^[^ ]/{s=$0} /:/{p=0} /ports:/{print s; p=1} p' file

serviceA:
   ports:
     8080
     1323
serviceB:
  ports:
     8081
     3123
```

capture service name, in case of `port:` match print service name and section, reset print flag `p` at the next subsection or section.

If you don't need the section names

```
$ awk '/:/{p=0} p; /ports:/{p=1}' file

     8080
     1323
     8081
     3123
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/:$/h;//d;G;/ports:$/P;d' file
```

Store each section name in the hold space and then delete that line. For every other line, append the most recent section name and if that happens to be `ports:`, print the current line only.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) and it is better to use a `YAML` parser to parse this data.

You may use this `ruby` code to print `ports` that are are at second level in all top sections:

```
ruby -ryaml -e "data=YAML::load(STDIN.read); data.each{|n|puts n.last['ports']}" < file.yml
```

```
8080 1323
8081 3123
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I want to find decision without new installations. I want to use standard Linux tool